# SQL finding no activity between dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find how many days that the company from EmployeeActivity Table using Postgres did not have any activity of an joining an employee or cutting employees. Null refer to they who still do activity inside the company meanwhile DateLeave refer to them leaving the company or not working anymore.

```
DateJoined   DateLeave     Name
................................
2012-06-20   NULL          Terrence
2012-06-21   2013-06-23    Mady
2010-06-20   2012-06-24    Greg
2013-06-20   NULL          Matt
```

my trials for this was

```
select EXTRACT(DAY FROM MAX(EmployeeActivity.DateJoined) - MIN(EmployeeActivity.DateLeave) 

From EmployeeActivity

WHERE EmployeeActivity.DateLeave IS 'NULL'
```

However it shows wrong value, especially for longer table

Output Expectation: 
My expectation for this output is to query the longest period of days that the company have no activity in assigning or firing Employee.

Comment: Based upon the data set provided, what would the desired result set look like?

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the feedback i have rewrote the question

Comment: You showed us what you have tried but not what you expect as an output based on the data you have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, the following should meet your needs:

```
    SELECT
        ActivityDate,
        lag(ActivityDate) over (ORDER BY ActivityDate) as PreviousActivityDate,
        Date_Part('day',ActivityDate - lag(ActivityDate) over (ORDER BY ActivityDate)) as Difference
    FROM
        (
        select DateJoined as ActivityDate from EmployeeActivity
        union
        select coalesce(DateLeave,now()) from EmployeeActivity 
        ) AllActivityDates
    ORDER BY Difference DESC
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

The reason for the `OFFSET 1` is because the earliest `DateJoined` doesn't have a previous row, and that one comes to the top, we're just skipping it.

Comment: thanks for the reply this is exactly what i need, does coalesce choose between "dateleave" and "now"? @steve-lovell

Comment: `coalesce` outputs the first of the supplied parameters which isn't `null`, so for a person who has no leave date, it gives the current date (and time).

Comment: thanks, for PreviousActivityDate and Difference, may i know why the query written like this. I think this is the last question, since i haven't yet to understand these 2 functions after surfing the web @steve-lovell

Comment: The important part of those is the `lag` function. It's what's known as a `window function` and enables queries to look across rows in useful ways. However for these to work, the code has to know how to order (and sometimes how to group) the data, which is where the `OVER (ORDER BY ...) ` comes in. Window functions can be very useful and are certainly worth learning about.

Comment: That said, you can usually achieve the same thing by other means, but it would normally involve at least one extra subquery and often makes your code harder to understand.

Comment: great! i'll check out these functions to have further learning. thanks again for your lesson